# Does tangle closure determine the triviality of the tangle?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Let $NS(T), D_+(T), D_-(T)$ denote closures of a $2$-tangle $T$ as in the picture. $T_0$ (below) is called trivial.

**Question**: Suppose that $NS(T)$ and $D_+(T)$ are trivial knots.
Does it imply that $T$ is either $T_0$ or $T_2=$ the 2-braid with 2 negative crossings?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The branched double covers $\Sigma(NS(T))$ and $\Sigma(D_+(T))$ are both $S^3$ by assumption, and they're each built by gluing $\Sigma(T)$ to the branched double cover of a different rational tangle (i.e., a solid torus).  This means that we can Dehn fill $\Sigma(T)$ along two different slopes to get $S^3$, so by the solution of the knot complement problem it must be an unknot complement.  In other words, $\Sigma(T)$ is a solid torus, and so $T$ must be a rational tangle.

The closure $NS(T)$ is the "numerator closure" of $T$, and if its branched double cover is $S^3$ then $T$ must have fraction $\frac{1}{q}$ for some integer $q$, so $T$ is a 2-braid with some number $q$ of signed crossings.  Now it's straightforward to identify $D_+(T)$ as the $(2,q+1)$ torus link, so this is only the unknot if q is 0 or -2, meaning if $T$ is either $T_0$ or $T_2$.

Comment: Many thanks, Steven -- it is a very clever argument. I am only bit confused about the implication that because $\Sigma(T)$ has 2 different fillings giving $S^3$, it must be an unknotted solid torus. How does it follow from knot complement problem? Doesn't one need some version of "cosmetic surgery" saying that if two different Dehn surgeries on $K$ are $S^3$ then $K$ is trivial?

Comment: The core of one filling is a knot $K$ in $S^3$, and then the other $S^3$ filling is a nontrivial Dehn surgery on $K$.  Since $K$ has a nontrivial $S^3$ surgery, it must be the unknot (this is theorem 2 of Gordon--Luecke, "Knots are determined by their complements"), and so its complement is a solid torus.